# Android: How can I handle the press of the keys?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, keypress, keyevent

I want to get a key pressing time, in milliseconds.

`Example` if User press 'F' key i want to get the value in milliseconds of the pressing time.

```
 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
    int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // start timer
            inizio = System.currentTimeMillis();
            break;
        case KeyEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // end timer
           long  diffInSec = (System.currentTimeMillis() - inizio);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Click durato " + diffInSec, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is not a such pre-define method but you can count time between key press down and key press up

```
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
    switch( keyCode ) { 
        case KeyEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // end timer
            break;
        case KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // start timer
            break;

     }
}
```

Comment: I test the program but it doesn't work. "the method keyPressed is never used"